# Nearest symmetric matrix, of a given spectrum, to a given diagonal matrix

Tags: matrices

Let $D_1$ and $D_2$ be real, $m\times m$ diagonal matrices, and define
$$f(U)=\|D_1-U^\intercal D_2 U\|_F\;,$$
a function on $m\times m$ orthogonal matrices $U$. This is a "nearest matrix" problem in the Frobenius ($F$) norm.

I conjecture that the minimum of $f$ is always attained when $U$ is a permutation matrix. Any help proving this conjecture, or finding a counterexample, will be much appreciated! It's enough if you can prove that permutation matrices are the only critical points of $f$. If it helps, you may assume the elements of $D_1$ and $D_2$ are distinct real numbers.

Comment: This follows from the Hoffman-Wielandt Theorem. See [this Math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1711713/hoffman-wielandt-theorem-proof), for example.

Answer (score 6):

This is treated as Problem A in Moody T. Chu and Kenneth R. Driessel, *The Projected Gradient Method for Least Squares Matrix Approximations with Spectral Constraints* ([doi](https://doi.org/10.1137/0727062), [nonpaywalled pdf](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.72.5877&rep=rep1&type=pdf)). They give your desired result in the case of distinct eigenvalues. They also point to a follow up paper treating the case of repeated eigenvalues.

ADDED: The proof suggested in the comment by Nathaniel Johnston is much simpler than the one I pointed to. I thought I would include it here for completeness since it is very short:

$$\begin{aligned}
f(U) &= \mathrm{tr}(D_1 - U^T D_2 U)^2 \\
&= \mathrm{tr}(D_1^2+D_2^2-2D_1U^TD_2U) \\
&= \mathrm{tr}(D_1^2+D_2^2-2(\mathbf{d}_1 \mathbf{d}_2^T)(U\circ U))
\end{aligned}$$
Since $U\circ U$ is doubly-stochastic it is a convex combination of permutation matrices. Since $f(U)$ is affine in $U\circ U$, it can be no smaller than the smallest value attained by a permutation matrix.

Comment: P. Diaconis informs me that the same argument was given by Hale Trotter in "Eigenvalue distributions of large Hermitian matrices; Wigner's semi-circle law and a theorem of Kac, Murdock, and Szegö." Advances in mathematics 54.1 (1984), page 73.

Answer (score 1):

This more than answers my question, thank you! Much as I like Birkhoff-von Neumann, something more elementary would go over better with my audience. Here's what I came up with:

We'll assume the elements of $D_1$ are distinct and for finding critical points will work instead with the simpler function
$$g(U)=\mathrm{Tr}(D_1 U D_2 U^\intercal)\;,$$
which differs from $f$ by a factor $-2$ and constants.

We are interested in the linear variation with $X$ of $g(U+X)$, where $X$ is subject to a linear constraint to keep $U+X$ orthogonal. From
$$1=(U+X)(U+X)^\intercal=1+XU^\intercal+(XU^\intercal)^\intercal+O(X^2)\;,$$
we see that this constraint is that $XU^\intercal$ is antisymmetric. Let $A$ be any $m\times m$ antisymmetric matrix, then $X=AU$. Using this for the parametrization of the perturbation, we obtain
$$g(U+AU)=g(U)+\mathrm{Tr}\left(A(UD_2U^\intercal D_1-D_1UD_2U^\intercal)\right)+O(A^2)\;,$$
where we used $A^\intercal=-A$. The linear term has the form $\mathrm{Tr}(AB)$, where $B$ is also antisymmetric. Since $A$ is any antisymmetric matrix, $\mathrm{Tr}(AB)=0$ implies $B=0$. To evaluate $B$, first define $C_2=UD_2U^\intercal$, and work out the $(i,j)$ element, for $i\ne j$:
$$(B)_{i j}=\left((D_1)_{jj}-(D_1)_{ii}\right)(C_2)_{ij}\;.$$
Since these are all zero, and the elements of $D_1$ are distinct, this shows that $C_2$ is diagonal. But $C_2$ has the same spectrum as $D_2$, so the basis change $U$ must be just permutations and sign flips of the basis.